# "Uncaught ReferenceError" from d3 with importmaps on Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I have little experience of building charts with d3 but not general web dev. I want to build a charting example site and opted to use Ruby on Rails. I'm having trouble getting d3 library to be working. I am a complete newbie to Rails. This is my steps

1. Used `./bin/importmap pin d3 --download` to get a local version of d3. I can see a number of d3 files under the  vendor/javascript folder. This has also created a number of records in importmap.rb e.g. `pin "d3" # @7.4.4`
2. In the application.js file I have: `import  "d3"`
3. I have test js file called "charts" and referencing this with `import "./charts"` in application.js
4. Test file contains

```js
window.onload = function() {var svg = d3.select("#rankChart1")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 1000)
                .attr("height", 1000);
                }
```

5. This fails with "Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined. I can see a number of d3 files under the Assets folder in the browser so not sure why it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With importmaps `d3` is not exported globally, that's why you're getting an error.

Pin `d3`:

```
$ bin/importmap pin d3
```

A whole lot of pins gets added. You can use all of them:

```js
import * as d3 from "d3";      // NOTE: every d3 module is loaded
```

Or just pick and choose for faster load time:

```
import {zip} from "d3-array";  // NOTE: from `name` has to match the pin `name`
```

or make a custom d3 object:

```
const d3 = await Promise.all([
  import("d3-array"),
  import("d3-axis"),
]).then(d3 => Object.assign({}, ...d3));
```

If you want the old behavior where `d3` is just global. Add this pin manually to *config/importmap.rb* file:

```
pin 'd3', to: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7'
```

and then just import it:

```
// app/javascript/application.js

import "d3";
import "chart"; // import after d3

console.log(d3); // d3 is already global and can be used anywhere.
```

```
// app/javascript/chart.js

console.log(d3.select); // d3 is loaded correctly
```

For more options: *https://github.com/d3/d3#installing*

Comment: I tried using `import * as d3 from "d3"` in application.js but it still doesn't find the d3 function.

Comment: @Jez you need to have an import where you use d3. otherwise you can swich to `jsdelivr` cdn. i've updated the answer, see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for you advice but doing that way with the cdn not the local version does not work for me either!

Comment: looks like the issue is not with d3, but with your js setup. I can't really debug the problem, unless I can reproduce it. Put everything in one file, check if d3 is loaded, restart the server, clear your d3 from vendor folder.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did clear the vendor folder and restarted and it now works.