# D3 component not showing up in Rails 7

Tags: d3.js, ruby-on-rails-7

I have been trying to use D3 in Rails 7, following the steps in the [alpha release video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtxZvFnL2i0). I know it's just a pre-release but the question is more generally, how to get D3 working in Rails 7. When I inspect the browser, the SVG is created but the Network tab does not list D3 bundle, which (I think) means it wasn't imported. Here's what I've added to the app files:

```
**application.html.erb**
<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
```

```
**importmap.rb**
pin "d3", to: "https://esm.sh/d3?bundle"
```

```
**application.js**
import "components"
import "components/d3_component"
//= require jquery3
//= require d3
```

```
**view.html.erb**
<svg width = '300' height = '200'><svg>
```

```
**d3_component.js**
import { select, zoom } from 'd3';

const data = {
    nodes: [
        {id: 1, x: 100, y: 50},
        {id: 2, x: 50, y: 50},
        {id: 3, x: 150, y: 50},
    ],
    links: [
        {source: 1, target: 2},
        {source: 1, target: 3},
    ]
};

const svg = select('svg');
const g = svg.append('g');

const handleZoom = (e) => g.attr('transform', e.transform);

const zooming = zoom().on('zoom', handleZoom);

select('svg').call(zooming);

....
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, what worked for me was adding
`<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>`
to `application.html.erb`

Comment: For those struggling with implementing d3 in Rails 7, I recommend checking out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78173598/rails-7-is-not-importing-javascript-files?noredirect=1#comment137821965_78173598 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72211936/uncaught-referenceerror-from-d3-with-importmaps-on-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to pin the directory

***importmap.rb***

```
pin_all_from "app/javascript/components", under: components"
```

And on the application.js you only need to import the component not the folder:

***application.js***

```
import "components/d3_component"
```

Doing the import with script would be against what DHH is trying to show on the video...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had tried that for several components and it didn't work. I'll try again.